# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" while using bind

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

**html:**

```
<input @bind="title"/>

<div id="chat-bottom-button-right-row">                
  <button @onclick="(() => RunMovie(title))">Chat</button> //I'd like to use title from input
</div>
```

c# code:

```
[Inject]
    public IJSRuntime Js { get; set; }
    private MovieDataDetail movieDetail = null;

    string title;
    private async Task RunMovie(string title)
    {
        movieDetail = await TmdbApi.GetAllMovieInfo(title); //Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("kinX").AsTask();
    }
```

I'd like to use title from `input`.

`title` always null even if I write something to `input`

Comment: `title` shouldn't be null all the time and you can write an `if(){}` to handle it. But how about `TmdbApi` ?

Comment: How did you create `TmdbApi` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two-way binding (i.e. the input is populated from the variable AND the variable is updated by the input) then use:

```
<input @bind-value=@title />
```